# OpenGL (python) - display an image?

Tags: python, opengl

I'm trying to use PyQT and the Python binding for OpenGL to display an image on a rectangle. So far, here's my code:

```
gVShader = """
              attribute vec4 position;
              attribute vec2 texture_coordinates;   
             varying vec4 dstColor;
             varying vec2 v_texture_coordinates;

            void main() {    
                v_texture_coordinates = texture_coordinates;
                gl_Position = position;    
            }"""

gFShader = """   
            uniform sampler2D texture1;
            varying vec2 v_texture_coordinates;

            void main() {

                gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, v_texture_coordinates);
            }"""   
class ProjectiveGLViewer(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProjectiveGLViewer, self).__init__(parent)


    def initializeGL(self):

    # load the shaders source code

        vshader = QtOpenGL.QGLShader(QtOpenGL.QGLShader.Vertex, self)
        if not vshader.compileSourceCode(gVShader):
            print vshader.log()

        fshader = QtOpenGL.QGLShader(QtOpenGL.QGLShader.Fragment, self)
        if not fshader.compileSourceCode(gFShader):
            print fshader.log()

    # create the shader program, compile, attach shaders to the program, link and use the program

        self._program = QtOpenGL.QGLShaderProgram()
        self._program.addShader(vshader)
        self._program.addShader(fshader)
        self._program.link()
        self._program.bind()

    # data array (2 [position], 2 [texture coordinates])

        data = np.array([-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)

    # create a buffer and bind it to the 'data' array

        self.bufferID = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.bufferID)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.nbytes, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

    # tell OpenGL how to handle the buffer of data that is already on the GPU

        loc = self._program.attributeLocation("position")
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 16, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        loc = self._program.attributeLocation("texture_coordinates")
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 16, ctypes.c_void_p(8))    

        self._imageTextureID = glGenTextures(1)

        image = QtGui.QImage("image.jpg")
        ptr = image.bits()
        ptr.setsize(image.byteCount())
        image_data = np.asarray(ptr).reshape(image.width(), image.height(), 4)

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  self._imageTextureID)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width(), image.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data)

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self._imageTextureID)

        self._program.setUniformValue('texture1', 0)


    def paintGL(self):
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.bufferID)
        glClearColor(0, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
```

Not too sure what i'm doing wrong here, but i'm getting back a black rectangle. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your texture is [incomplete](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture). You are not setting filtering and wrap modes. Add these after `glTexImage2D`:

```
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST )
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST )
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT )
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT )
```

Comment: ...or upload a complete set of mipmaps.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But any reason it's being displayed vertically flipped (maybe to coordinates i'm sending in the array are in the wrong order?) and the color space is a bit off?

Comment: You could flip the v-coordinate in the shader: `v_texture_coordinates.y = 1.0 - v_texture_coordinates.y`

Comment: Thanks! any idea why the color space changed?

Comment: If the colors are inverted, replacing the second `GL_RGBA` in `glTexImage2D` with `GL_BGRA` could help. Depends on the prescence of an alpha channel in the texture.

Comment: Yeah that indeed fixed it.. why though? Why would the format data of the pixels be GL_BGRA and not GL_RGBA?